# How to manage sortable iterator state in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I'm writing a custom iterator , which supports drag and drop to reorder the list. I am not sure how i can update the order of admin/resources/xxx/data.

I have tried to set component state from props, but since react-admin use cloneElement everywhere, it's very fragile.

now the code look like this:

```
const Sortable = props => (
  <Datagrid {...props} body={<SortableBody />} />
)

const SortbaleBody = connect({null, {dispatchSortableUpdate}})((props) => (
  const sortable = useMemo(() => Object.values(props.data), [data]);
  const moveRecord = (newData) => {
    dispatchSortableUpdate({data: newData})
  }
  return (
    <DragDropContextProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
      <TableBody>
        {sortable.map((record, index) => React.cloneElement(SortableRow, props, children))}
      </TableBody>
    </DragDropContextProvider>
  )
))
```

This is the react-dnd sortable example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/react-dnd/react-dnd/tree/gh-pages/examples_js/04-sortable/simple?fontsize=14

How i can update the order of admin/resources/xxx/data? Am i doing Sortable right?

Answer (score 0):

I end up using

```
const sortable = useMemo(() => Object.values(data).sort((a,b) => a.position - b.position))

const moveRecord = (dragIndex, hoverIndex) => {
  const dragRecord = sortable[dragIndex];
  const hoverRecord = sortable[hoverIndex];

  dragRecord.position = hoverIndex + 1;
  hoverRecord.position = dragIndex + 1;
  dispatchSortableUpdate({ id: dragRecord.id, data: dragRecord });
  dispatchSortableUpdate({ id: hoverRecord.id, data: hoverRecord });
}
```

```
const sortableUpdate = ({ id, data }) => ({
  type: SORTABLE_UPDATE,
  payload: {
    id,
    data,
  },
  meta: {
    resource: 'xxx',
    fetchResponse: UPDATE,
    fetchStatus: FETCH_END,
  },
});
```